# Equivalent of SELECT 0 as something but for strings. Is it SELECT '' as something?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the equivalent of:

```sql
SELECT 0 as foo;
```

but for strings, is it:

```sql
SELECT '' as bar;
```

?

For more context, this is for a `UNION ALL` query

[edit]

SELECT NULL is what I was looking for.
In the top query I was doing: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(bar))`,
But empty strings counted as a distinct char, `NULL` doesn't.

Comment: What are you trying to do? That will fail because you're trying to union two different datatypes.

Comment: What is *equivalent*? What the issue you have with `select '' as something` and why it doesn't fit your needs? You are free to try it by yourself and ask the question about the exact issue.

Comment: The standard way is to select `NULL`, independent of data type.

Comment: @jarlh NULL is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want an "equivalent" of `SELECT 0` in string form, then it would be `SELECT '0'::int`.

If you are looking for a non-null string to represent 'no data,' `SELECT '' AS something` would suffice

When you call `UNION ALL`, the expectation is that the columns would align and the data sets would be concatenated along their column orders.  Since you want to `UNION ALL` an `integer` and `char`, you will get an error:

```
edb=# select 0 as something union all select '' as something;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: ""
LINE 1: select 0 as something union all select '' as something;
                                               ^
```

Therefore, in order to `UNION ALL`, you'll want to cast your `0` as a `char`:

```
edb=# select 0::char as something union all select '' as something;
 something 
-----------
 0
 
(2 rows)
```

### Caveat

I'm not sure if this is really what you want to do, but if you're looking to `UNION ALL` the two sets, that's how you'd do it.  However, there's a chance this would open up a can of worms -- is `''` going to be considered equivalent to `0`?  And what will you do with non-zero values?  Will you still cast those `integer`s into strings?  I think you'll need to think through those implications and try to find a way to sanitize your data.

In general, it might be better to work with `NULL` values if your design allows for it

Comment: " a non-null string to represent 'no data,'" - why?

Comment: I don't know -- we'll have to see what OP says.  I've seen some cases, however, where the column is `NOT NULL`, so you'd have to fudge that with `''`.  Ugly, yes...

Comment: @jarlh At least because `0` and `null` are different in numeric datatype. And if we consider a concatenation as an equivalent to addition on strings, they will be aligned. Though, `''` is definitely not a data absence (as zero too), but some *initial* value. Anyway, explicit type definition is more reliable way when selecting constants (regardless of null or not)

Comment: @astentx, an empty string would I usually call a broken value. NULL has a purpose.

Comment: @jarlh It is a theoretical question. Empty string is much easier to handle in filter or join. For example, many BI applications by default display `null` as `null` text in the UI which is not what business user wants to see (especially for non English speaking users). It cannot be selected from drop-down list alongside the other values, which is translated into `in (<list of values>)`. It always require special processing even when absence is acceptable, which may cost a lot of development and maintenance effort.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond! I updated my question for more context